# Is there a way to see a complete stack trace from android?

Tags: android

When I get an uncaught exception in my app and the trace prints to the logcat, is there anyway to make the entire trace print out?  At the end of the trace it always has something like "...10 more".

Example:
`03-11 16:25:53.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3297): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.notify.notifymdm.listeners.PackageInstallerReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/net.notify.notifymdm-2.apk]
03-11 16:25:53.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3297):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
03-11 16:25:53.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3297):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
03-11 16:25:53.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3297):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
03-11 16:25:53.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3297):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2780)
03-11 16:25:53.572: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3297):     ... 10 more`

Comment: Why do you need that? The real cause is always the first line in the trace where it says "Case by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException". It can't find net.notify.notifymdm.listeners.PackageInstallerReceiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the "...N more" represents n more lines of the same error, anyway.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#printStackTrace%28%29