# Stack traces never trace back to application code

Tags: android

I'm not sure why but it seems with newer releases of android I never get usefull stack traces. They don't seem to go back far enough for me to find what line of code caused the crash. Example:

```
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.evidence/com.evidence.activity.EvidenceList}: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1183)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389): Caused by: android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.throwIfCursorIsClosed(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:75)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.database.BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.requery(BulkCursorToCursorAdaptor.java:144)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.database.CursorWrapper.requery(CursorWrapper.java:186)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:4505)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:4531)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
08-17 09:33:38.449: E/AndroidRuntime(14389):    ... 10 more
```

Is there a way to get the "10 more" that are not being shown?

```
public class EvidenceList extends StandardMenuActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private ApplicationSettings settings;
    private Context mContext;
    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Uri mData;

    private ImageButton mActiveButton = null;
    private static final String TAG = EvidenceList.class.getSimpleName();
    protected static final int ACTION_LOGIN = 10;
    protected static final int ACTION_ENTER_PIN = 11;
    protected static final int ACTION_BULK_EDIT = 12;

    private static final int DIALOG_CONFIRM_DELETE = 2;
    private static final int DIALOG_LOADING = 3;
    private static final int DIALOG_FILES_MISSING = 4;

    private static final int MENU_ITEM_CANCEL_UPLOAD = 10001;
    private static final int MENU_ITEM_DELETE_EVIDENCE = 10002;
    private static final int MENU_ITEM_VIEW_EDIT_EVIDENCE = 10003;
    private EvidenceDBHelper evidenceHelper;
    protected UploadQueueHelper upHelper;
    private ListView mListView;
    EvidenceListCursorAdapter mAdapter;    
    private ImageButton mListAllButton, mListAudioButton, mListVideoButton, mListPhotoButton, mListUploadedButton;
    private Button uploadButton;
    private View actionButtonBar, tabButtonBar;    
    private TextView mTitleView;

    private Button mSelectAllButton, mImportButton;
    private EvidenceManager mEvidenceManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        settings = ApplicationSettings.getInstance(mContext);

        mEvidenceManager = EvidenceManager.getInstance(mContext);
        setContentView(R.layout.evidence_list);

        actionButtonBar = findViewById(R.id.EvidenceSelectedItemsActionButtonBar);
        tabButtonBar = findViewById(R.id.EvidenceListTabBar);

        mData = getIntent().getData();
        if (mData == null) {
            mData = LocalEvidence.CONTENT_URI;//default data
        }
        upHelper = new UploadQueueHelper(mContext);
        evidenceHelper = new EvidenceDBHelper(mContext);

        mListAllButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.EvidenceListAllTabButton);
        mListVideoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.EvidenceListVideoTabButton);
        mListAudioButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.EvidenceListAudioTabButton);
        mListPhotoButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.EvidenceListPhotoTabButton);
        mListUploadedButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.EvidenceListUploadTabButton);
        mTitleView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.EvidenceListTypeTitle);
        mSelectAllButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CheckAll);        
        mImportButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ImportEvidence);
        mImportButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(DIALOG_IMPORT_EVIDENCE);
            }
        });
        mSelectAllButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {   
                EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "select_all", "on", 1);
                Toast.makeText(mContext,  getString(R.string.message_select_all), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                mAdapter.checkAll();
            }           
        });

        ListHasCheckedItemsListener checkedItemsListener = new ListHasCheckedItemsListener() {

            @Override
            public void onListCheckedStatusChange(boolean hasCheckedItems) {
                showTabsOrButtons(hasCheckedItems);

            }
        };
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        mListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
        mCursor = getCursor();
        mAdapter = new EvidenceListCursorAdapter(this, mCursor, getUriForCursor(), checkedItemsListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate, cursor: " + mCursor + " with adapter@uri " + getUriForCursor());
        uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.UploadEvidenceButton);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        setActiveButton();
        checkIfIntentHasTab(getIntent());

        UploadManagerService.startUploader(this, UploaderAction.OP_START, 1, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        checkIfIntentHasTab(intent);
    }

    private void checkIfIntentHasTab(Intent intent) {
        String tab = getIntent().getStringExtra("tab");
        if (tab != null) {
            if (tab.equals("uploads_completed")) {
                changeView(R.id.EvidenceListUploadTabButton);
            } else if (tab.equals("all_evidence")) {
                changeView(R.id.EvidenceListAllTabButton);
            } else if (tab.equals("videos")) {
                changeView(R.id.EvidenceListVideoTabButton);
            } else if (tab.equals("photos")) {
                changeView(R.id.EvidenceListPhotoTabButton);
            } else if (tab.equals("audio")) {
                changeView(R.id.EvidenceListAllTabButton);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "no match for tab " + tab);
            }
        }
    }


    public void titlebarLogoClicked(View button) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Clicked titlebar");
        launchMainActivity();
    }

    public void launchMainActivity() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    //should be called after switching the cursor
    private void setActiveButton() {
        if (mData.equals(LocalEvidence.CONTENT_URI)){
            mActiveButton = mListAllButton;
        } else if (mData.equals(LocalEvidence.CONTENT_AUDIO_URI)){
            mActiveButton = mListAudioButton;
        } else if (mData.equals(LocalEvidence.CONTENT_VIDEO_URI)) {
            mActiveButton = mListVideoButton;
        } else if (mData.equals(LocalEvidence.CONTENT_PHOTO_URI)) {
            mActiveButton = mListPhotoButton;
        } else if (mData.equals(LocalEvidence.CONTENT_UPLOADED_URI)) {
            mActiveButton = mListUploadedButton;
        }
        mActiveButton.setSelected(true);
        setOthersInactive(); 
    }
    private void setOthersInactive() {
        if (mActiveButton != mListAllButton) {
            mListAllButton.setSelected(false);
        }
        if (mActiveButton != mListVideoButton) {
            mListVideoButton.setSelected(false);
        }
        if (mActiveButton != mListAudioButton) {
            mListAudioButton.setSelected(false);
        }
        if (mActiveButton != mListPhotoButton) {
            mListPhotoButton.setSelected(false);
        }
        if (mActiveButton != mListUploadedButton) {
            mListUploadedButton.setSelected(false);
        }
    }

    private void changeCursor() {
        mAdapter.changeCursor(getCursor());
    }


    private Cursor getCursor() {        
        return managedQuery(mData, null, null, null, null);
    }

    private Uri getUriForCursor() {
        return LocalEvidence.CONTENT_URI;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
        mAdapter.close();
        super.onDestroy();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume");
        if (!FileUtils.isExternalStorageAvailableAndWritable(mContext)) {
            Util.showAlertMsgNoExternalStorage(this);
            return;
        }
        if (settings.requiresPin() && settings.getLastPinSuccessEntryTime() < System.currentTimeMillis() - (1000 * 60 * 15)) {
            sendToEnterPin();
            return;
        }
        //Set<Long> selections = mAdapter.getSelectedCheckboxMediaIds();
        //setTabsOrButtons(selections);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        //super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        //outState.
    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onListItemClick, item clicked with id " + id);
        Intent openEvidenceIntent = getIntentForEvidenceId(id);
        startActivity(openEvidenceIntent);
    }

    private void uncheckAll() {
        mAdapter.uncheckAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed");

        if (mAdapter.hasSelectedCheckboxes()) {
            uncheckAll();
        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);         
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
            //super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog");
        switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_CONFIRM_DELETE:
                String msg = getString(R.string.alert_delete_imported);
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setMessage(msg)
                        .setCancelable(false)
                        .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes_btn),
                                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                        EvidenceList.this.doRemoveEvidence();
                                    }
                                })
                        .setNegativeButton(R.string.no_btn, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).create();
            case DIALOG_LOADING:
                ProgressDialog pdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                pdialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_checking_login));
                return pdialog;
            case DIALOG_FILES_MISSING:
                return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(getString(R.string.alert_files_missing_title))
                        .setMessage(getString(R.string.alert_files_missing))
                        .setNeutralButton(getString(R.string.ok_btn), new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1id) {
                                dialog.cancel();
                            }
                        }).create();
            default:
                return super.onCreateDialog(id);
        }

    }

    public void removeEvidence(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "removeEvidence");
        //Toast.makeText(mContext,  "Going to delete.. ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        showDialog(DIALOG_CONFIRM_DELETE);
    }

    public void bulkEditEvidence(View v) {
        Log.d(TAG, "bulkEditEvidence");
        EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "bulk_edit", "", 1);
        Set<Long> selections = mAdapter.getSelectedCheckboxMediaIds();
        Iterator<Long> selectionIter = selections.iterator(); 
        // Pass the array of id's checked to the intent service. 
        // We need to convert from Long[] to long[] 
        long[] ids = new long[selections.size()];
        int i = 0;
        while(selectionIter.hasNext()) {            
            long curr = selectionIter.next();
            ids[i++] = curr;
        }
        Intent bulkEditIntent = new Intent(this, BulkEditEvidence.class);
        bulkEditIntent.putExtra(BulkEditEvidence.EXTRA_EVIDENCE_IDS, ids);
        startActivityForResult(bulkEditIntent, ACTION_BULK_EDIT);
    }

    public void doRemoveEvidence() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doRemoveEvidence");
        EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "delete", "", 1);
        Set<Long> selectedIds = mAdapter.getSelectedCheckboxMediaIds();
        if (selectedIds == null || selectedIds.size() < 1) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext,  getString(R.string.alert_no_evidence_removed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        Iterator<Long> selectedIter = selectedIds.iterator();   
        List<Long> deleted = new ArrayList<Long>();
        while(selectedIter.hasNext()) {
            long selectedId = selectedIter.next();
            Log.d(TAG, "going to delete evidence id: " + selectedId);
            Evidence ev = evidenceHelper.getEvidencefromMediaRecord(selectedId);

            if (ev != null) {
                if (ev.getMediaId() > 0) {
                    //has a media id
                    int rowsAffected = evidenceHelper.deleteById(selectedId);
                    upHelper.deleteById(selectedId);
                    if (rowsAffected >0) {
                        deleted.add(selectedId);                         
                    }
                } else {
                    if (ev != null) {
                        try {
                            ev.getFile().delete();
                            int rowsAffected = evidenceHelper.deleteById(selectedId);
                            upHelper.deleteById(selectedId);
                            if (rowsAffected > 0) {
                                deleted.add(selectedId);
                            }
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "error trying to delete evidence  " + selectedId + " msg: " + e.getMessage(), e);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                String msg = String.format(getString(R.string.alert_ev_with_id_could_not_delete), "" + selectedId);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        if (deleted != null && deleted.size() > 0) {
            Long[] deletedArr = deleted.toArray(new Long[1]);
            mAdapter.uncheckIds(deletedArr);
        }
        try {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_CONFIRM_DELETE);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //who cares
        }
    }
    public void uploadSelected(View v) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {     
        Log.d(TAG, "uploadSelected");
        uploadButton.setEnabled(false);
        showDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
        //if the last time the session was checked was more than 15 minutes (-5 seconds)
        //then check the session again..

        if (!settings.canUserAutoLogin()) {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
            sendToLogin();
        } else {
            doUploadSelected();
            uploadButton.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }

    private void sendToLogin() {
         Intent i = new Intent(Action.LOGIN);         
         startActivityForResult(i, ACTION_LOGIN);
    }

    private void sendToEnterPin() {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, EnterPin.class), ACTION_ENTER_PIN);
    }

    private void doUploadSelected() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doUploadSelected");

        Set<Long> selections = mAdapter.getSelectedCheckboxMediaIds();
        Iterator<Long> selectionIter = selections.iterator(); 
        // Pass the array of id's checked to the intent service. 
        // We need to convert from Long[] to long[] 

        Long[] origArr = selections.toArray(new Long[selections.size()]);
        Log.d(TAG, "about to pass evidence IDs for upload | on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        List<Long> toUpload = new ArrayList<Long>(); 
        long[] ev_ids = new long[selections.size()];
        int i = 0;
        boolean alertMissing = false;
        while(selectionIter.hasNext()) {
            long curr = selectionIter.next();
            Evidence ev = evidenceHelper.getEvidencefromMediaRecord(curr);
            if (FileUtils.isFileAvailableAndReadable(ev.getFile())) {
                toUpload.add(curr);
                ev_ids[i] = curr;
                i++;
            } else {
                alertMissing = true;
            }
        }
        try {
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
        } catch(Exception e) {}

        if (alertMissing) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_FILES_MISSING);
        }
        if (ev_ids.length < 1) {
            return;
        }
        EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "upload_selected", "" + ev_ids.length + " items" , 1);
        UploadManagerService.startUploader(this, UploaderAction.OP_QUEUE_UPLOAD, 1, ev_ids);

        uploadButton.setEnabled(true);
        mAdapter.markIdsAsDisabled(origArr);

    }

    private void onLoginResult(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "login", "on", (resultCode == RESULT_OK) ? 1 : 0);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            doUploadSelected();         
        } else {
            try {
                dismissDialog(DIALOG_LOADING);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            uploadButton.setEnabled(true);
            Toast.makeText(mContext, getString(R.string.alert_cannot_upload_without_internet),  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {                
        Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult");

        switch (requestCode) {
            case ACTION_LOGIN:
                onLoginResult(resultCode, data);
                return;
            case ACTION_ENTER_PIN:
                if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {                
                     finish();//throw error message
                 }
                return;
            case ACTION_BULK_EDIT:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    uncheckAll();
                }
                return;
            case ACTION_IMPORT_AUDIO:
            case ACTION_IMPORT_VIDEO:
            case ACTION_IMPORT_PHOTO:
                onImportResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;                
            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    private void onImportResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        ImportAction action = ImportAction.IMPORT_PHOTO;
        if (requestCode == ACTION_IMPORT_AUDIO) {
            action = ImportAction.IMPORT_AUDIO;
        } else if (requestCode == ACTION_IMPORT_VIDEO) {
            action = ImportAction.IMPORT_VIDEO;
        }
        EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "import", action.toString(), resultCode == RESULT_OK ? 1 : 0);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Evidence ev = mEvidenceManager.importEvidence(this, intent, action);
            if (ev != null) {
                launchEvidenceListActivity(null);
                BackupService.start(this, BackupService.OP_DATA_CHANGED);
            }
        }
    }


    public void showTabsOrButtons(boolean hasCheckedItems) {        
        if (hasCheckedItems) {
            tabButtonBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            actionButtonBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); 
            if (mData.equals(LocalEvidence.CONTENT_UPLOADED_URI)) {
                actionButtonBar.findViewById(R.id.UploadEvidenceButton).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                actionButtonBar.findViewById(R.id.BulkEditEvidenceButton).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                actionButtonBar.findViewById(R.id.UploadEvidenceButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            actionButtonBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tabButtonBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void changeView(int id) {
        Uri newUri = null;
        String newTitle = "";
        if (id == R.id.EvidenceListAllTabButton) {
            newUri = LocalEvidence.CONTENT_URI;
            newTitle = getString(R.string.tab_all_pending_upload);
            EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "switched_tab", "all", 1);
        } else if (id == R.id.EvidenceListAudioTabButton) {
            newUri = LocalEvidence.CONTENT_AUDIO_URI;
            newTitle = getString(R.string.tab_audio_pending_upload);
            EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "switched_tab", "audio", 1);
        } else if (id == R.id.EvidenceListPhotoTabButton) {
            newUri = LocalEvidence.CONTENT_PHOTO_URI;
            newTitle = getString(R.string.tab_photos_pending_upload);
            EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "switched_tab", "photos", 1);
        } else if (id == R.id.EvidenceListVideoTabButton) {
            newUri = LocalEvidence.CONTENT_VIDEO_URI;
            newTitle = getString(R.string.tab_video_pending_upload);
            EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "switched_tab", "videos", 1);
        } else if (id == R.id.EvidenceListUploadTabButton) {
            newUri = LocalEvidence.CONTENT_UPLOADED_URI;
            newTitle = getString(R.string.tab_all_uploaded);
            EasyTracker.getTracker().trackEvent(TAG, "switched_tab", "uploaded", 1);
        }

        //only change something if its a different view
        if (!mData.equals(newUri) && newUri != null) {
            mData = newUri;
            changeCursor();
            setActiveButton();
            mTitleView.setText(newTitle);
        }
    }
    public void changeView(View button) {
        changeView(button.getId());
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5278794/is-there-a-way-to-see-a-complete-stack-trace-from-android

Comment: no, those are usually more errors caused by this error and will not include which line in your code caused the crash. It looks like it might be in your onResume, somewhere where you are accessing a cursor that is no longer valid.

Comment: This is a perfectly valid stack. You are having a managed Cursor, even then you have closed the cursor manually. You should post your code

Comment: I have not closed the cursor anywhere in my code, I have however closed the adapter which uses the cursor (in onDestroy). Would that cause it?

Comment: post the code. only then can we know

Comment: is it a custom adapter because none of the adapters have a close function. If it is and close is doing close on cursor then either you should not call it or you should manage the cursor by yourself

Comment: Oh yeah that is a custom adapter, unfortunately this is what close does:   public void close() {
     mContentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(progressObserver);
     mContentResolver.unregisterContentObserver(statusChangeObserver);
    }

No closing the cursor their either.. I also looked through the adapter code and I never close the cursor their either..

Answer (score 0):

There is a great free tool I use, [BugSense](http://www.bugsense.com/) which is very easy to insert to your app, and when a crash occurs it tells you the line number that caused the crash. It also
notifies you about crashes, giving you information about the android version, the app version, number of previoius occurences, device state, and much much more.

Here is an example from my very application crash report:
[image]

Comment: I actually do use bugsense.. However, it won't include anymore information than is in the bugtrace reported by logcat AFAIK.

Comment: In fact, lately most of my crash logs in there have had no relevant line in my code which caused the crash.. This latest one was just the one that had me upset because it seems to happen more often on ICS/jellybean devices than on gingerbread and froyo

Comment: Yes. When it is a runtime exception there is no line number,
But it did give you useful information:
`android.database.StaleDataException: Attempted to access a cursor after it has been closed.`
So you are trying to access a cursor after it was closed.
I would suggest that you debug your code in the sections where you use the cursor, and then you can discover what causes the error